# How to debug a npm link module from another npm link module?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code

It is a complicated context so I will try to be as explicit as possible.

For this scenario I have 4 projects:

1. A (TypeScript project)
2. B (TypeScript project)
3. C (TypeScript project)
4. D (Angular project written in TypeScript)

> The projects A, B and C are symlinks (created with `npm link`), B is
>   linked with C, A and C are linked to D,
>
> It's as follows:

```
D/node_modules/
D/node_modules/A
D/node_modules/C
D/node_modules/C/node_modules/
D/node_modules/C/node_modules/B
```

When I use this configuration in VS Code:

```
{
            "name": "Attach2",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:8085/",
            // This forces chrome to run a brand new instance, allowing existing
            // chrome windows to stay open.
            "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "trace": true,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--preserve-symlinks"
            ],
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///./*": "${webRoot}/*",
                "webpack:///*": "*",
                "webpack:///dist/*": "${webRoot}/dist/*",
                "webpack:///./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*",
            }
        }
```

I can only debug A and C from project D, the main problem is that with the debugger I can't reach the project B and see what's happening there so... I want to know how I can debug the 3 projects (A, B and C) when only D is running?
Is a specific configuration required in webpack?

> Note: All projects have their source maps.

Comment: Have you try to run your app (the D one) in debug mode as usual and go inside node_module/A and set your breakpoint?